# Skyrim vampirism

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Esbern and Delphine keep attacking me. I understand it is from vampirism but how do I drink blood to reverse the stages? I'm getting annoyed with everyone attacking me. Help?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to drink blood is to find someone sleeping in their bed and interact with them. Feed is one of the options.